# NameError from simple self-made class

Tags: python, python-3.4, nameerror

I've created the following Vertex class:

```
"""VERTEX CLASS"""  
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, name, total_weight, path_so_far):
    self.name = name
    self.total_weight = total_weight
    self.path_so_far = path_so_far

  def __str__(self):
    return "(" + str(name) + "," + total_weight + "," + path_so_far + ")"
```

and am attempting to make an Object of said class like this:

```
 t = Vertex(item[0],item[2],item[1])
```

When I compile my program, I receive the following error on the stack:

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

I've checked other NameError entries on stack, and so far haven't seen any fixes that pertain to my situation. What am I missing?

Comment: Put a `self.` in front of all the field names in `__str__`. Like you did in `__init__`.

Comment: Also, your doctoring belongs **inside** the class definition.

Comment: Duhhh thanks! Want to make an official answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

```
Put a self. in front of all the field names in __str__. Like you did in __init__. – a_guest
```